# Distance formula

Tags: java, formula, distance

I need help with a lab. My teacher did not tell us anything and he told us to figure it out. So i can use any help I can get. Thank You

**Step 1**: Is everything good with step one including my distance formula and I am trying to set `xx` equal to `x` and `yy` equal to `y` so I have not clue how to do that could could you help me with that.

```
    class Point {
        private int x;
        private int y;

        public Point()                          // (0, 0)
        {
          x = 0;
          y = 0;
    }

        public Point(int xx, int yy)
        {  
           xx = x;
           yy = y;
    }

        public int getX()                       // return field values
        {
            return x;
    }
        public int getY()
        {
            return y;

    }

        // Use the distance formula to find the distance of this point from the origin (0,0)
        public double distanceFromOrigin()
        {
                int d = 0;


                d = Math.squrt(Math.pow(xx - x) + (Math.pow(yy - y);
}
```

Is my distance formula good if not what is wrong and can you help me fix it.

**Step 2**: I need to find the manhattan distance

```
// Find the "manhattan" distance between current point and other.
//  You can look at http://x...content-available-to-author-only...t.gov/dads//HTML/manhattanDistance.html for help
public double distance(Point other) 
{/*write the code for here*/}
```

I really have no clue how to do step 2 so i can really use a lot of help thank you guys so much

**Step 3**: After i find the manhattan distance between current point and other. I need to change it to its new values which i have no clue how to get the new value and how to change it. After that i need to shift the point by the translation T which i have no clue how to do that so i need help on that

```
// Changes the coordinate to new values
public void setLocation(int x, int y)
{/*write the code for here*/}

//Shift the point by the translation T<x+h,y+k>
public void translate(int h, int k)
{/*write the code for here*/}
```

by the way guys I am just on the basic computer science so I can't use all the fancy stuff so keep it basic and simple

Comment: This looks like Java, not JavaScript

Comment: Also, why would you remove this link from your step2? http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/manhattanDistance.html

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry

Comment: `d = Math.squrt(Math.pow(xx - x) + (Math.pow(yy - y);` should be `d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xx - x) + (Math.pow(yy - y));`  that is sqrt not squrt and the closing bracket at the end.. BTW this is the JavaScript forum not JAVA.

Comment: @Blindman67 this is not a JavaScript forum....

Comment: Class? Type `double`? `Public`? What is this, Java?

Comment: @epascarello My bad thought I was in the JS forum.. will edit out the BTW..Oh can not edit it,...Oh well so be it..

Comment: @Blindman67 You can copy its content and delete the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Like torvin said in the comments, that really looks like Java and not Javascript. Those are two different languages, despite the similar names.

Generally looking at your code, there are obvious mistakes, which make me wonder what IDE (integrated development environment) you are using to write code. A proper program that helps you write code will spot those.

Just in your distanceFromOrigin() you are missing:

- 2 closing bracets
- Math.squrt() should be Math.sqrt()
- You are not returning a value, despite having set the methods return type to double

You should probably first set up an IDE and do a basic Java tutorial before continuing, honestly.